# Easiest way to set the font style for a column in PGFplotstable

Tags: tables, pgfplotstable, columns

My question seems to be very simple but I haven't found a simple solution.

I just want to set the j-th column of the table to be typeset in boldface.
What is the best and simple way to do that?

What code should I write in

```
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    columns/j-index/.style = { ... }
]{data.txt}
```

?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{example.dat}
a b        
1 1.1e-01
2 2.2e-02
3 3.3e-03
4 4.4e-04
5 5.5e-05
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Example table with second column in bold}\vspace{10pt}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
every head row/.style={
before row=\toprule,
after row=\midrule
},
every last row/.style={
after row=\bottomrule
},
columns={a,b},
columns/a/.style={
int detect,
column name=A
},
columns/b/.style={
column name=\textbf{B},
sci,sci zerofill,
precision=3,
postproc cell content/.append style={@cell content/.add={\boldmath}{}}
}
]
{example.dat}
\end{table}
\lipsum[1][1-2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That was really useful.

Comment: @RoSánchezMartínez You're welcome. If you feel the answer solve your question, you should consider to accept it.